# Django missing underscore in models name from admin

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm working on a project using [Django cookie cutter](https://cookiecutter-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

I have an issue with adding a through model (EventCompetitor) to my app for additional info related to a many to many relationship (competitors).

I can see in the db that the through table is called: "events_event_competitor" but Django throws an error in the admin because its trying to query: "events_eventcompetitor".

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "events_eventcompetitor" does not exist
```

what would cause this issue?

## models.py

```
class EventCompetitor(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey('Event', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    competitor = models.ForeignKey(Competitor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Meta:
    
    unique_together = ('event', 'competitor')

class Event(models.Model):
    """
    Default custom evens model for oddsx.
    """

    # Choices for the status field
    STATUS_CHOICES = [
        ('CANCELLED', 'Cancelled'),
        ('LIVE', 'Live'),
        ('SCHEDULED', 'Scheduled'),
        ('POSTPONED', 'Postponed'),
        ('FINISHED', 'Finished'),
    ]

    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Event name", max_length=30)
    slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name="Slug", max_length=30)
    sport = models.ForeignKey(Sport, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="events")
    competition = models.ForeignKey(Competition, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="events", null=True)
    competitors = models.ManyToManyField(Competitor, through='EventCompetitor', through_fields=('event', 'competitor'))
    status = models.CharField(verbose_name="Status", max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='SCHEDULED')
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Start date", null=True, blank=True)
    venue = models.CharField(verbose_name="Venue", max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(verbose_name="City", max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Events"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

## admin.py

```
@admin.register(Event)
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("name",)}
    list_display = ("name", "slug", "country", "sport")
    list_filter = ("country", "sport")

@admin.register(EventCompetitor)
class EventCompetitorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('event', 'competitor', 'order')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `Django` automatically generates the table name for the through model based on the names of the models involved in the many-to-many relationship. in your case the through model is called `EventCompetitor`, and Django expects the corresponding table name to be `events_eventcompetitor`.
- you can explicitly specify the `db_table` attribute in the `Meta` class of your EventCompetitor model. Update your `EventCompetitor` model as:

```py
class EventCompetitor(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey('Event', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    competitor = models.ForeignKey(Competitor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'events_event_competitor'
        unique_together = ('event', 'competitor')
```

By setting `db_table` to 'events_event_competitor', you are explicitly telling Django to use that table name when querying the database.
After making this change, try running the `migrations` again to update the database schema.